# Need help to make bond prices iterable for different assumptions of discount rate (Python v3.10.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance

**
Info: Im using Python 3.10.6**

I'm currently trying to come up with a function for bond prices that can iterate / go thru different interest rates. The end goal is to create simulation of bond prices based on CIR model.

Basically, to calculate bond prices I need to pre-define two other functions. These two functions would then need to be multiplied together, and summed up, to give bond prices

- bond cash flows
- discount factors

Bond cash flow function:

```
def bond_cash_flows(maturity, principal=100, coupon_rate=0.03, coupons_per_year=12):
    n_coupons= round(maturity*coupons_per_year)
    coupon_amt= principal*coupon_rate/coupons_per_year
    coupon_times=np.arange(1, n_coupons+1)
    cash_flows=pd.Series(data=coupon_amt, index=coupon_times)
    cash_flows.iloc[-1] += principal
    return cash_flows
```

Discount factor function

```
def discount(t,r):
    discounts = pd.DataFrame([(r+1)**-i for i in t])
    discounts.index = t
    return discounts
```

Finally, bond price function

```
    
def bond_price(maturity, principal=100, coupon_rate=0.03, coupons_per_year=12, discount_rate=0.03):
    cash_flows=bond_cash_flows(maturity, principal, coupon_rate, coupons_per_year)
    discounts= discount(cash_flows.index, r=discount_rate/coupons_per_year)
    return (pd.DataFrame(cash_flows)*discounts).sum()
```

What seem to work:

- Bond price function works fine when I hardcode the rates(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYq4x.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYq4x.png)
- Cash flow and discount function works [image]

What did not work:
When I try to plug in the list of rates into the bond price formula, it throws me this error. Usually it throws me some kind of dimension error as well, if it wasn't this error message
[image]

My desired output:

- Able to input a list of rates and the formula can loop thru  the rates and output diff bond prices for each rates
  [image]

Appreciate your inputs on this. Apologies as I'm beginner in Python (but not finance)

I  tried to come up with the functions and changed different inputs into certain datatypes to ensure the function can handle the inputs.

However I get thrown off everytime by different kind of value or dimensional error.

The desired output is basically ability to input parameters into bond price function and pass on more than 1 interest rates, output being bond prices at different interest rates.

I hope it's clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are using variable `discount` as local variable inside function `discount(t, r)` and `bond_price`.

> If you set the value of a variable inside the function, python
> understands it as creating a local variable with that name. This local
> variable masks the global variable.
>
> In your case, `discount` is considered as a local variable, and it's used
> before being set, thus the error.

To solve this problem, you can explicitly say it's a global by putting `global discount` in your function.

See the references below:

- [UnboundError](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)
- [nonlocal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal)

example:

```
def discount(t,r):
    global discounts
    discounts = pd.DataFrame([(r+1)**-i for i in t])
    discounts.index = t
    return discounts
```

Other solution:
You can fix this by passing parameters rather than relying on Globals variable

example:

```
def discount(t, r, discounts):
    # we use 'discounts' variable from parameter
    # discounts = pd.DataFrame([(r+1)**-i for i in t])
    discounts.index = t
    return discounts
```

Hope it helps.

*Be careful when using variable with the same name in Python.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering how to make bond prices functions that are iterable when passed a list of rates, here is the solution:

```
def discounts(t,r):
    discounts = pd.DataFrame([(r+1)**-i for i in t])
    discounts.index = t
    return discounts

def bond_cash_flows(maturity, principal=100, coupon_rate=0.03, coupons_per_year=12):
    """
    Return a series of cash flows generated by a bond, indexed by a coupon number
    """
    n_coupons= round(maturity*coupons_per_year)
    coupon_amt= principal*coupon_rate/coupons_per_year
    coupon_times=np.arange(1, n_coupons+1)
    cash_flows = pd.DataFrame(data=[coupon_amt for i in coupon_times], index=coupon_times)
    cash_flows.columns = ['bond_cf']
    cash_flows.iloc[-1] += principal
    return cash_flows


def bond_price(maturity, principal, coupon_rate, coupon_per_year, rates):
 rate_input = pd.DataFrame({'rates': [i / coupon_per_year for i in rates]})
 cf = bond_cash_flows(maturity, principal, coupon_rate, coupon_per_year)
 discount_df = discounts(cf.index, rate_input.iloc[:,0])
 bond_price = pd.DataFrame()
 bond_price['disc_rate'] = rates
 bond_price['price'] = discount_df.mul(cf['bond_cf'], axis=0).sum()
 return bond_price
```

Thank you